# Problems Burning Ubuntu onto USB - OS X

Tags: boot, command-line, system-installation, usb

I've followed this [guide](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) by Ubuntu.com on how to create a bootable USB of Ubuntu. Ive even followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mndO508xq08) on YouTube. I have follwed it to the letter and all I get from the USB afterwards is the error message:

"The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer."

And i'm not able to boot from it.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks
Harry

Comment: The first link provided is for Windows ?

Comment: Oh sorry I just pasted the wrong link. I've been doing it through OS X's Terminal.

Comment: To be able to boot, you should have a FAT32 filesystem on your USB, but I thought OSX wasn't able to handle FAT32?

Comment: It can but I don't know it's limits if it even has any. I formatted the USB to FAT using OS X, whether this would effect anything upon boot up I don't know. But many people have done it so I would imagine not? I know that mine doesn't work as always. :/

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error. In my case it was because I created a 64 bit bootable USB on a 32 bit machine (my Mac mini). That may be your issue as well. I am trying to boot this usb on a 64 bit machine, which is not a complete succes so far.

Comment: Mines definitely a 64bit system but I'll try 32bit. Can't see what I'm doing wrong... :/